# How to generate dynamic callgraph of a jmh benchmark ?

Tags: java, call-graph, jmh

I want to generate `callgraph` from a benchmark written using the framework `jmh`. I am using https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph for that.
I have tried generating a static callgraph for the jar file `target/benchmarks.jar` and it works. Now I want to generate the dynamic callgraph, so I used the following command:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -jvmArgs "-javaagent:target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-agent.jar"
```

But no output file `callgraph.txt` is created.

Comment: JMH forks the JVM multiple times during benchmarking in order to discard any side effects. I don't think what it is a good idea to generate call graph for generated code but if you want you can disable forking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating a dynamic call graph for a regular Java application first? Or, at least, try to invoke the host JVM with javaagent? The mere fact static call graph works does not imply the dynamic should.

If you would try dynamic, then you'll realize it does not "work" even without JMH involved. And the trick is to "include" the classes to instrument:

```
java -jar ~/projects/jmh/jmh-samples/target/benchmarks.jar \
    -jvmArgs "-javaagent:target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-agent.jar=\"incl=org.*\"" \ 
    Hello -f 1 -wi 5 -i 5
```